# Accessing sitecore content with virtual folders

Tags: url, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

### The Issue

We have two sites, one domain, we want to setup a virtual directory on the domain which can access the second site.

IIS virtual directory doesn't seem to do the trick, sitecore does not seem to play nicely.

Is there a potential work around using sitecore?

### The Environment

We have the following folder structure for two of our sites:

- C:\Sitecore\Site1
- C:\Sitecore\Site2

Site 1 and Site 2 both connect to the same web, core and master databases.

To access the cms for both sites in the browser we do:

- www.mysite1.com/sitecore

From Site 1's cms we create content, layouts and templates for Site 1 and Site 2.

### The Solution

What we did is in the first sites web.config we defined the site as normal:

```
<site name="site1" hostName="mysite1.com" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/MyItem1/" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
```

In the second sites web.config we defined the site slightly differently:

```
<site name="site2" hostName="mysite1.com" virtualFolder="/Site2" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/MyItem2/" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
```

The second site we defined a virtual folder which you can notice above that was the only difference along with the obvious start item differences.

Site 1 will respond like normal. You can visit mysite1.com it will load the start item relevant for website 1.

When you visist mysite1.com/Site2/ it will load the virtual folder defined in the second site and load its relevant start item.

That is pretty much it works like a charm.

And finally @Mark Ursino thanks for your help.

### To Note

You need have sitecore scalability configs enabled for any of the above to work

Comment: Please provide the `<site ...>` configuration from your `web.config`

Comment: Added the configs so you can see what I am essentially trying to do.

Comment: Got it. Hmmm, I'm a bit confused about how `myitem` relates to `/Partners/UK/` or `/Partners/NZ/`... is one of those what `myitem` is?

Comment: Yeah sorry there is only one site, with a start item of lets say: /MyItem/ ammended above.

Comment: So when you access `www.example.com/myitem-no2/` does it render that item? But when you call LinkManager.GetItemUrl(...) it renders as `www.example.com/sitecore/content/myitem/myitem-no2/`? I'm still not sure what the issue is fully.

Comment: Additionally, can you show (with bullets) how your tree structure is setup?

Comment: Apologies for delay in reply I was dragged into a meeting. Adding update to question and clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I think I understand, I think you need to make some changes in the config to set the "sub-folder site" as a `virtualFolder`:

```
<site virtualFolder="/subsite" physicalFolder="/subsite" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/MyItem/" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
```

Note that `virtualFolder="/subsite"` and `physicalFolder="/subsite"` point to the subfolder, but I don't think you need that physical folder really there.

[Reference used](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/site%20Attribute%20Properties/virtualFolder.aspx).

Comment: I assume this worked? I'm more curious for my own knowledge as I've never done something like this and had to look it up.

Comment: I have rewritten the entire question so you can get a better idea. @Mark Ursino

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this post will be useful http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2012/02/have-sitecorecontent-in-your-link-time.html

Comment: Close but not quite what the specific question asks for. I like how Alex Shyba links to my blog in his post though! :-D